# C#/ASP.NET - Repeater with a HTML select

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval, repeater

I'm trying to display some data within a select using the following code:

```
<select name="area" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterArea" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <option value="<%# Eval("Id") %>"><%# Eval("Area") %></option>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</select>
```

But unfortunately I get the following error: `The server tag is not well formed.`

If I try to change it to `value="<%# Eval('Id') %>"` I get an error saying: `CS1012: Too many characters in character literal`

Any suggestions would be very welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other poster mentioned, use a DropDownList.  They are very easy to use.

On your ASPX page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And in your code behind:

```
DataTable dtItems = GetData();
DropDownList1.DataSource = dtItems; // Pretty much anything that can be iterated over or a collection (DataTable, List, etc)
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Some Field"; // This is what the user sees. If this is a DataTable, "Some Field" is the name of a column in the table.
DropDownList1.DataValueVield = "Some Unique Value"; // Again, "Some Unique Value" is a column in the DataTable
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

It's really easier than you might think, even if you're new to ASP.Net.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want do it this way, why not just use a dropdownlist control.

Comment: That is possibly a better option thank you, to be honest I'm having a hard time transitioning from PHP where you have full control of the markup

Comment: Definitely use a DropDownList!

Comment: If you want to have full control of the markup, I would suggest ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value='<%# Eval("Id") %>'><%# Eval("Area") %></option>
```

You need single quotes around the eval statement.

Comment: Many thanks! It runs now, but my select tag is empty... the option tags aren't being displayed on the screen :(